# insert JSON document while maintaining uniqueness of a field

Tags: json, postgresql

Trying to update/insert a JSON record in postgresql (9.5.4) with the following table:

```
create table (detail jsonb);

insert into table VALUES ('{"name": "tom", "zip": 88717, "city": "dallas"}');
```

Suppose I get from UI a JSON `{"name": "tom", "zip": 78717, "city": "houston"}` that I want to update/insert while maintaining the uniqueness of name field.  Tried the following but gets error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "->"
LINE 2: on conflict (detail->'name')
```

Here is the SQL statement that caused the error:

```
insert into jsonTest VALUES ('{"name": "tom", "zip": 78717, "city": "houston"}') 
on conflict (detail->'name') 
do update set  detail = '{"name": "tom", "zip": 78717, "city": "houston"}'::jsonb where  detail->>'name' == 'tom';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you created the UNIQUE index on `detail->>'name'`, your insert should look like this:

```
insert into jsonTest VALUES ('{"name": "tom", "zip": 78717, "city": "houston"}') 
on conflict ((detail->>'name'))
do update set  detail = '{"name": "tom", "zip": 78717, "city": "houston"}'::jsonb
```

I just added another parenthesis to the `on conflict ((detail->>'name'))` and removed the where clause.

EDIT: To create an unique index on `detail->>'name'` you can do the following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX jsonTest_name_index ON jsonTest((detail->>'name')) ;
```

After the index is created, you can use the "INSERT ON CONFLICT" without problems.

Comment: Thanks @j-alderete, how to create a unique index in this case?